# woocomerce Automatically add product to cart on visit - error

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm trying to implement the following solution:

```
/*
 * goes in theme functions.php or a custom plugin
 **/
// add item to cart on visit
add_action( 'init', 'add_product_to_cart' );
function add_product_to_cart() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        global $woocommerce;
        $product_id = 64;
        $found = false;
        //check if product already in cart
        if ( sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                $_product = $values['data'];
                if ( $_product->id == $product_id )
                    $found = true;
            }
            // if product not found, add it
            if ( ! $found )
                $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        } else {
            // if no products in cart, add it
            $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        }
    }
}
```

from here:
http://docs.woothemes.com/document/automatically-add-product-to-cart-on-visit/

but it throws an error:

> Sorry, this product cannot be purchased.

Anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

Comment: So do you have a product with an id = 64?

Comment: Hei, good catch - I actually changed the value of the id from 64 to 1, but it appears my product had the id 42.

Go figure, 42 **is** the answer :))

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe your product stock quantity is zero or product is not there. Please check that.

Comment: the product id was wrong, as you and user574632 pointed out.

Thank you! :)